# Select query using the condition

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, grails

I have three tables here.The user is able to apply the training available.when he/she selects the training then it is placed at TRAINUSER table according to his/her userID. I want to SELECT the user when he/she logs in and to show data from TRAINUSER table which he/she has not applied the training. Like user_id 1 has applied 2 and 3 training but has not applied 1 and 4 training. I want user_id 1 to show with training 1 and 4 using hibernate query.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on the part where you have tried something and it didn't work?

Comment: Sounds like a outer join with a null condition. But not 100% sure

Comment: yes bro i am weak in hibernate so i m not getting the solution

Comment: you may be weak in hibernate but your mspaint game is lit. Still, you're probably not going to get much help on SO if you don't show any attempt, and I hope you're not really storing the plaintext password.

Comment: select 
* 
from `training` 
where id NOT IN (select t.train_id from `user` u INNER JOIN `trainuser` t on u.id = t.user_id where u.id = 1) it is the required sql query i did now how to change it it hibernate query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of this will depend on what your domain classes look like, you could use executeQuery like so:

```
Training.executeQuery( "from Training tr where tr.id not in ( select t.id from TrainUser tu join tu.training t join tu.user u where u.username = :uname )", [uname: 'ADMIN'] )
```

Assuming the following domains, only relevant fields included:

```
class User {
    String username
}

class TrainUser {
    static hasMany = [training: Training, user: User]
}

class Training {
    String name
}
```