# Using the select innner join in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, grails, hibernate-mapping

I have three tables user,training and trainuser. A user can apply for the trainings available in the training table. I want to only show the list of training_name from training table where the user has not applied. I have written the following sql :

```
select * from 'training' where id NOT IN (select t.train_id from 'user' u INNER JOIN 'trainuser' t on u.id = t.user_id where u.id = 1)
```

As the user with id=1 logs in. I want to change it to a hibernate query for grails. How can I translate it ? I have put an image of my database schema

[Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xoy0k.png)

Comment: Did you look at the documentation here : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html ? Do you have a sample of what you tried in HQL ? You might get more answers if you try and share what you've already done.

Comment: I have tried HQL as  "Training.executeQuery("from Training Tr where tr.id NOT IN(Select t.train_id from 'User' u INNER JOIN 'TrainUser' t on u.id=t.user_id where u.id=t.user_id where u.id=uid)",[uid:userId])"

Comment: Seems remarkably similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49892314/select-query-using-the-condition

Comment: @MikeW Indeed, it does even the name. Weird.